# WebPack with React Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm very loosely following the example [here](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/#integration) up until the point where it starts running the dev server.

I have a test React component (in scripts/test.jsx):

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');

var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <h1>HI!</h1>
    }
});

module.exports = Test;
```

I have a webpack.config where I'm using the jsx loader against the source directory (It's basically the same as the one in [the example](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/#integration) except I'm adding the [library properties](http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)).

I run webpack and it generates the bundle file like I expect, however, when I try to use the component in an html file (after including the bundle.js script reference) I get the following in console:  "**Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined**".

The HTML contains the following:

```
<div id="hi">
</div>
<script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    React.renderComponent(
      <Test />,
      document.getElementById('hi')
    );
</script>
```

Am I doing something incorrect to use a component that is defined in CommonJS style against an html page that isn't technically using a module loader (I'm trying to treat this test as if it's someone who is trying to load the component without any type of structured module loader)?

The output of the webpack is available [here](https://gist.github.com/ryanlanciaux/25d492ec75d47a2f49f9)

EDIT 2: The full example code is available [as a github repo](https://github.com/ryanlanciaux/testReactWebpack)

Comment: How does the scrip look like in e.g. the Chrome debugger? Do the compiled scripts appear correctly in the Resources tab?

Comment: I have updated the question to include a link to the compiled output. The scripts are appearing in the resources tab of Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you'd be better off following the example and requiring `Test` from a .jsx file rather than inlining it in the HTML.

Otherwise, `Test` needs to be exported as a global, so you'd need to follow similar conventions to the browserify `--standalone` flag, which looks to be something like this:

```
output: {
    library: "Test",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
}
```

http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-for-browserify-users.html#standalone

Edit: After looking at your GH repo, you have:

```
<script src="bundle.js" type="text/js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so it wasn't loading bundle at all. Further, you can't have 2 separate copies of react, the way you have it currently you're requiring React from within webpack, and then you're also loading it on the page. You should either export a function which takes the React object, or use the global to be able to use it outside of the bundle.

For example this would work:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
module.exports = function(React) {

var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <h1>HI!!</h1>
    }
});

return Test;
};
```

and then:

```
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    React.renderComponent(
      Test(React)(),
      document.getElementById('hi')
    );
```

or this

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <h1>HI!!</h1>
    }
});

module.exports = Test;
```

and then:

```
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    React.renderComponent(
      <Test />,
      document.getElementById('hi')
    );
```

Though I can't imagine most folks consuming a React package are going to be loading it with a script tag, and you generally don't want globals, so it's probably best to just use the CommonJS style require and let people figure out shimming or whatever.

Comment: I know that UMD contains var / require / common structure but shouldn't setting libraryTarget to var also make the component available to the page? http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Comment: Also, I agree it's not a great practice to use this inline HTML. The problem is that I'm working on a library for others to use and I don't want to make too many assumptions on their setup (beyond saying you need React, etc). UMD is a good option for that (because it can be used Common/Require/inline) but setting UMD option has same behavior. I was testing with var first and that seemed like the simplest way to start.

Comment: So are you still having issues with the var/umd configs?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I can toss the test project on GitHub or something a little later on so the full source is available. It really seems like there has to be a config option or something I'm missing but not entirely sure what.

Comment: I've loaded the basic example to github - https://github.com/ryanlanciaux/testReactWebpack

Comment: Edited answer based on gh repo

Comment: wow the text/js thing was really dumb :) I started out with that as jsx and converted to javascript -- yea, deleting the x in jsx won't work :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking the time to look at this and explain some of these concepts. I'm pretty new to the browserify / webpack mindset -- really liking it so far.